# type inference is smart enough to figure out the type when the type is operated with other type

Tags: scala, type-inference

Assume this type inference code for infer Element in the List,

```
def doStuff[A](x: List[A]) = x // ignore the result 

doStuff(List(3)) // I dont need to speicify the type Int here
```

However, if the type A is operated with other type, the type inference is not working, I have to specify the type.

```
def doStuff[A, B](x: List[A], f: (B, A) => B) = {

}

doStuff(List(3), (x: String, y) => x) //compilation failed, missing parameter type
doStuff[Int, String](List(3), (x, y) => x) //compilation fine.
```

May I know why is that ?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type inference only works across separate argument lists. If you change `doStuff` to the following:

```
def doStuff[A, B](x: List[A])(f: (B, A) => B) = {

}
```

Type inference will work as you expect:

```
doStuff(List(3))((x: String, y) => x)
```

However, note that type inference is left to right, so if you put `Nil` as a first argument, it will infer `A = Nothing`, which is almost never what you want.

**UPDATE**

In your original example, the call `doStuff(List(3), (x: String, y) => x)` fails, since the type of `y` in the lambda cannot be inferred. The `List(3)` is in the same parameter list, so `A` is not yet known. Therefore, there is no hint to the type of `y` and the compiler fails.

Comment: I wanted to post same but then I figured out that is not the answer to OP question. Do you know why in `def doStuff[A, B](x: List[A], f: (B, A) => B): Unit` type of `A` cannot be infered?

Comment: So types in list parameters are only known after evaluating whole parameter list? It's not like: going from left to right, infering type of `List`, it's an `Int` so `type A = Int` so compiler knows that `f` is a function where second type is an `Int` ?

Comment: Exactly. That's one of the reasons standard library functions like `foldLeft` have two parameter lists.

Comment: That's what I wanted to clarify because your answer doesn't say it explicitly :)